# Delete an old message from user - Discord.js

Tags: discord, discord.js

I am currently making a bot that is used as a queue for people waiting in line. I am having difficulty deleting the old message that the user sent to be added to the queue (so that discord isn't cluttered).

What is the proper way to access and delete an old message from the client?

!next -> adds the person to the queue,
!remove -> should remove the first person in queue and delete the "!next" call that the user entered in chat.

```
client.on('message', message => {
    user = message.member;
    user = user.toString();
    idNumber = message.member.id;

   if (message.content === '!next') {
        x++;
       message.reply('Added to waiting queue. Position ' + x);
       arrayName.push(user);
       idName.push(idNumber);
       }
     else if (message.content === '!remove') {
         x--;
         arrayName.shift();
         idName.shift();
         message.reply('Removed Top User from Queue. Users Left: '  + x);
         //how to remove !next call from user that called it?
         }
```

Comment: I would suggest you just delete the `!next` message immediately regardless using `message.delete()` inside the first `if` statement

Comment: @Syntle I wanted to leave the !next message to make sure that the users could confirm that they were added to the list later on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would agree with Syntle in your comments, you should just delete it right away.

That said, if you really want to do this, here is the answer to the question:

You are going to need some kind of multi-dimensional storage for your queue.  There are multiple options, but I am going to demonstrate with an array of objects.

```js
if (message.content === '!next') {
    array.push({Id: idNumber, User: user, Message: message});
    message.reply('Added to waiting queue. Position ' + array.length);
} else if (message.content === '!remove') {
    let record = array.shift();
    message.reply('Removed Top User from Queue. Users Left: ' + array.length);

    if(!record.Message.deleted) {
        record.Message.delete();
    }
}
```

Comment: Would you also recommend doing the same thing if I wanted to delete the message reply that the bot sends in the !next?

Comment: @Sunny you could.  message.reply returns the new reply message, so you could push that in the object as well.  However, you will need to use array.length + 1 in the message because then you would be replying before actually pushing anything to the array.  Also remember that message.reply is a promise, so either use await or .then before pushing it to the array.